# Stop sending ajax request without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created ajax request that sends some data to php file on button click event. Now after submitting data I want to restrict the ajax request not to send the data again and again by clicking the button. It sends the data only on  page refresh ( means send data one time on page load ). How can I stop such requests. My ajax code is as follow :

```
$(".button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        url: 'my/ajaxrequest.php',
        data: {
            result: 'hi test data'
        },
        success: function (resp) {
            $("#result").html(resp);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just replace `.click()` by [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

This will prevent multiple clicks from running your `$.ajax()` again.

```
$(".button").one('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({ ... });
}
```

If you need to perform a post on page load only, you can simply move the `$.ajax()` call from the click handler into the document ready function:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:  'post', 
        cache:  false ,
        url:  'my/ajaxrequest.php',
        data:  { result : 'hi test data' },
        success: function(resp) {
            $("#result").html(resp);
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A deeper analysis could restrict the ajax call to one successful response (i.e. was the status 200 && did it return the result you're looking for? If so you can put this code in the `success` function of the XHR function: `requestLog.sendStatus = true;` if you only want to allow the ajax request to initialize once then put this ( `requestLog.sendStatus = true;`) right after the `e.preventDefault` If you want to only allow the ajax call to be prevented if the their was in fact a succesful response then put the `requestLog.sendStatus = true` in the `success` function of the ajax object.

```
var requestLog = {};
    requestLog.sendStatus = false;

$(".button").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if(requestLog.sendStatus) return;  
   /* requestLog.sendStatus = true; */
   $.ajax({
      type:  'post', 
      cache:  false ,
       url:  'my/ajaxrequest.php',
       data:  { result : 'hi test data' },
       success: function(resp) {
          $("#result").html(resp);
          requestLog.sendStatus = true;
      } 
     });
});
```

You want to run it on page load only once? Try this:

```
(function() {
  $.ajax({
     type:  'post', 
     cache:  false ,
     url:  'my/ajaxrequest.php',
     data:  { result : 'hi test data' },
     success: function(resp) {
          $("#result").html(resp);
     } 
  });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `click eventHandler` from button after successful Ajax response.

**Example**

`$("#Btn").unbind("click");`

**OR**

`$.off("click", "input:button", foo);`

Answer (score 0):

Just modify like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
$(".button").unbind('click'); //unbind the bound event after one click
    $.ajax({
        type:  'post', 
       cache:  false ,
        url:  'my/ajaxrequest.php',
        data:  { result : 'hi test data' },
        success: function(resp) {
      $("#result").html(resp);

        } 

      });

    });
```